# How to serialize Option<Vec<DateTime>> field to bson?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a struct defined like the following (other fields removed for brevity):

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Test {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    #[serde(with = "bson::serde_helpers::chrono_datetime_as_bson_datetime")]
    pub time_period: Option<Vec<DateTime<Utc>>>
}
```

And I'm using the following in my Cargo.toml:

```toml
[dependencies]
bson = { version = "^2.4", default-features = false, features = [ "chrono-0_4" ] }
chrono = "^0.4"
serde = { version = "^1.0", default-features = false, features = [ "derive" ] }
```

But the serde derivations throw error because it expects a `DateTime` object:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:4:39
    |
4   | #[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^
    |                                       |
    |                                       expected struct `chrono::DateTime`, found enum `std::option::Option`
    |                                       arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected reference `&chrono::DateTime<Utc>`
               found reference `&'__a std::option::Option<Vec<chrono::DateTime<Utc>>>`
note: function defined here
   --> /home/kmdreko/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bson-2.4.0/src/serde_helpers.rs:296:12
    |
296 |     pub fn serialize<S: Serializer>(
    |            ^^^^^^^^^
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Serialize` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:50
  |
4 | #[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
  |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::option::Option`, found struct `chrono::DateTime`
  |
  = note: expected enum `std::option::Option<Vec<chrono::DateTime<Utc>>>`
           found struct `chrono::DateTime<Utc>`
  = note: this error originates in the macro `try` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Any ideas how to serialize optional vector of `DateTime` objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serde's `with` attribute can only be used if your function/module expects the exact type of the field. That is not possible to change and sometimes you see `*_opt` functions/modules to provide support for `Option`s, but never for arbitrary nesting.

The `bson` crate has a feature to use `serde_with` to work around that. You need to enable the `serde_with` feature of `bson` and import `serde_with` v1 into your code. Note the extra `default` attribute to serde. That is unnecessary for v2 of `serde_with`, but `bson` is still on v1.

```rust
#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Test {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none", default)]
    #[serde_as(as = "Option<Vec<bson::DateTime>>")]
    pub time_period: Option<Vec<DateTime<Utc>>>
}
```

```toml
[dependencies]
bson = { version = "^2.4", default-features = false, features = [ "chrono-0_4", "serde_with" ] }
chrono = "^0.4"
serde = { version = "^1.0", default-features = false, features = [ "derive" ] }
serde_with = "1"
```

[Run on Rustexplorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/8anmlw)

Answer (score 3):

**Why doesn't the OP's code work**

The [`bson::serde_helpers::chrono_datetime_as_bson_datetime`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/serde_helpers/chrono_datetime_as_bson_datetime/index.html) module contains helper functions that (de)serializes *a single `chrono::DateTime` object*, so it doesn't work with the field of type `Option<Vec<DateTime<Utc>>>`.

**Solution using nested struct**

To (de)serialize such data, you can define a `struct TestInner` that contains the inner `DateTime<Utc>` object, along with [the `#[serde(transparent)]` container attribute](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html) so that it's (de)serialized in the same way as a single `DateTime<Utc>` object. For example, the `struct Test` in the question can be changed into something like this.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Test {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub time_period: Option<Vec<TestInner>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(transparent)]
pub struct TestInner {
    #[serde(with = "bson::serde_helpers::chrono_datetime_as_bson_datetime")]
    datetime: DateTime<Utc>,
}
```